# How to properly terminate Tor on a Python subprocess

Tags: python, selenium, terminal, subprocess, tor

*I'm doing this on Windows 10*

I want my python code to navigate through Tor using Selenium so I simply called subprocess.Popen on my tor.exe file (from Windows Expert Bundle, **not** the Tor browser) to start the Tor circuit, fetched https://check.torproject.org/ and everything works smoothly but, when I finish the program I notice the Tor connection didn't close:

```
λ NETSTAT.EXE -an | findstr 9050
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9050         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49964        127.0.0.1:9050         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49966        127.0.0.1:9050         TIME_WAIT
```

Here's my first attempt:

```py
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver

torexe = subprocess.Popen(r"\path\to\tor.exe", shell=True)
PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050"  # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
binary = r'D:\path\to\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=binary)
driver.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
torexe.terminate()
```

But the circuit is still open, so I thought of doing this:

```py
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
with subprocess.Popen(r"\path\to\tor.exe", shell=True) as torexe:
    PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050"  # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    binary = r'\path\to\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=binary)
    driver.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
```

But of course the program keeps working until I stop it manually.
I'm calling the tor.exe from the code directly to ease my work but if I execute it outside and suppress the `with...as` statement I can close the cmd prompt and the circuit closes.

I'd like to know the best approach to start the tor circuit from the code and close it when the program ends. As I said, **if I start tor.exe manually** and then Ctrl-C the cmd prompt, the connection closes, which is what I ultimately seek for.